# Is Android able to stream .m3u8 file?

Tags: android, streaming, android-mediaplayer, media

I'm trying to stream .m3u8 file using media player for Android. But it seems the media player failed to fetch the playlist:

Error log:

```
08-28 13:40:48.358: ERROR/LiveSession(8804): unable to fetch master playlist 'http://192.168.0.3:49152/live-streaming/192.168.0.5/6344.m3u8'.
```

The most frustrated things so far is I did this once and it worked fine, Once I tried for second time, blank screen just appeared.

Comment: Looks like there's an IP address in the middle of the URL. Is that correct? Have you tried opening the m3u8 in winamp?

Comment: yes, the IP address is the part of the URL, this url is working fine on the iOS platform. I was just wondering that m3u8 is supported by Android. i'm trying to play on VLC.

Comment: Is it possible to add code to your question? It's hard to debug without the code

Answer (score 1):

http://vov.io/vitamio/ This library supports m3u8. see if it works a little better.

Comment: exception throw once i used vitamio media player:


08-28 16:24:58.886: ERROR/MediaPlayerDemo(9386): io.vov.vitamio.VitamioInstaller$VitamioNotFoundException

Comment: You need to to install the Vitamio app as well as using there provided classes.

Comment: Is there any way to embed the Vitamio app into the project? I don't want the user to download an extra app.

Comment: @BenGroot : have u found solution to embed Vitamio

Comment: @Mohit, just a few weeks ago they have opened the gates to embed the player in your app: http://vitamio.org/vitamios?locale=en I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: @BenGroot : ya tried that .. and was successful .. but since API size is 4.8 mb's it makes app very bulky ... let me knw if u find any work around for this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a long shot, but have you tried httplive://192.168.0.3:49152/live-streaming/192.168.0.5/6344.m3u8 ?

Using that in html5 video elements works in Android 2.3.5 for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [ExoMedia](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia), a striped down easier-to-use version of Google's own ExoPlayer. Streams m3u8 well, easy as:

```
emVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("https://somewebsite.com/somepath/somelink.m3u8"));
```